# Adding custom projection in GDAL 3

Tags: gdal

I want to add custom projection to the GDAL library version 3.

In earlier versions (with Ubuntu 18.04) we directly added the definition to the `/usr/share/proj/epsg` file

In GDAL 3 the files do not exist any more, how can we add the custom projection?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in Proj library that is using different resource files since Proj version 6. The documentation is in https://proj.org/resource_files.html

> A number of init files come pre-bundled with PROJ but it is also
> possible to add your own custom init files. PROJ looks for the init
> files in the directory listed in the PROJ_LIB environment variable.

As an example I added a new code 900900 by copying the last entry of the file "others.extra" in my PROJ_LIB directory.

```
#  Funny epsgish code for google mercator - you should really use EPSG:3857
#
<900913> +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs <>
<900900> +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs <>
```

Now GDAL recognized this new custom projection as `+init=others.extra:900900`as can be verified for example with gdalsrsinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalsrsinfo.html. Notice the syntax, epsg:900900 does not work.

```
gdalsrsinfo +init=other.extra:900900

PROJ.4 : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["unknown",6378137,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

You can save your custom projection into file "epsg" in the PROJ_LIB directory but you must still use the +init syntax `+init=epsg:900900` and you'll get a warning `Warning 1: +init=epsg:XXXX syntax is deprecated. It might return a CRS with a non-EPSG compliant axis order.`

I think that EPSG definitions with only epsg: prefix are now searched from the proj.db database where they are stored from the official EPSG database. The infamous EPSG:900913 seems to be there as well as some sort of extra in the table "projected_crs". You can check that with any SQLite database client.

```
select * from projected_crs where code=900913;
result:
EPSG    900913  Google Maps Global Mercator NULL    NULL    EPSG    4499    EPSG    4326    EPSG    3856    EPSG    3544    NULL    1
```

Because of that GDAL finds epsg:900913 even without +init

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:900913

PROJ.4 : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["Google Maps Global Mercator",
...
```

If you want to add new custom, or fake, epsg codes and use them just as you have used to do then you should edit the proj.db database. However, I would not recommend to do it. Hopefully the +init syntax will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the detail answer. The problem is that I'm working with Django gis, so I have no way to add this manual +init. Is there a way to add this permanently?

Comment: I would ask that directly from the gdal_dev mailing list. Adding your own definition into your local proj.db database might be the right way, perhaps by using your own authority name instead of epsg. I do not know what happens when QGIS users add their custom projections but that could be a good model to follow.